# cmake cannot find arm64 Visual C++ compiler

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, arm64

I am using cmake 3.15.3 where I am trying to generate a Visual Studio 2017 ARM64 development environment.

Here is my cmake command:

```
cmake .. -G \"Visual Studio 15 2017\" -A ARM64
```

I have installed the appropriate ARM64 compiler tool chain using the Visual Studio 2017 installer.

So, if I create a project from inside the IDE, I can select ARM64 as a compilation target.

However, cmake cannot seem to locate an ARM64 Visual Studio C (or C++) compiler:

```
No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
```

Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Is what I am attempting even possible?

Comment: This works for me with CMake 3.15.3 and Visual Studio 16 2019. As far as I can tell, it should work with VS2017 as well, but I haven't tested that. It might help if you share `CMakeOutput.log` and `CMakeError.log` as they might have additional information about where CMake is looking for the compiler.